# Understanding DictVectorizer in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I'm exploring the different feature extraction classes that `scikit-learn` provides. Reading the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html) I did not understand very well what `DictVectorizer` can be used for? Other questions come to mind. For example, how can `DictVectorizer` be used for text classification?, i.e. how does this class help handle labelled textual data? Could anybody provide a short example apart from the [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html) that I already read at the documentation web page?

Answer (score 23):

say your feature space is *length*, *width* and *height* and you have had 3 observations; i.e. you measure length, width & height of 3 objects:

```
       length  width  height
obs.1       1      0       2
obs.2       0      1       1
obs.3       3      2       1
```

another way to show this is to use a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'height': 1, 'length': 0, 'width': 1},   # obs.2
 {'height': 2, 'length': 1, 'width': 0},   # obs.1
 {'height': 1, 'length': 3, 'width': 2}]   # obs.3
```

`DictVectorizer` goes the other way around; i.e given the list of dictionaries builds the top frame:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
>>> v = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
>>> d = [{'height': 1, 'length': 0, 'width': 1},
...      {'height': 2, 'length': 1, 'width': 0},
...      {'height': 1, 'length': 3, 'width': 2}]
>>> v.fit_transform(d)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.],   # obs.2
       [ 2.,  1.,  0.],   # obs.1
       [ 1.,  3.,  2.]])  # obs.3
   # height, len., width
```

Comment: Great explanation. So, what DictVectorizer does "in a nutshell" is vectorizing labeled observations regardless the "string" tags?.